# ListView change order to opposite direction ANDROID

Tags: android, listview, direction

I have a ListView filled with for loop. The data inside ListView is now in direction

- 6
- 5
- 4
- 3
- 2
- 1

and I want it to be in proper direction:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6

Comment: So fill it properly, what's the problem and the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections.sort is probably what you're up for!

http://www.vogella.de/blog/2009/08/04/collections-sort-java/

Answer (score 0):

Just loop in the other direction.

Instead of

```
for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++){
    // fill array with values ...
}
```

do

```
for(int i = 6; i > 0; i--){
    // fill array with values ...
}
```

Comment: Yup did that ... But was thinking about any more elegant way to do this... Is there any?

Answer (score 0):

Use Collections.reverse(arrayList);
This will automatically reverse the data.